# why -(id)init not see my objects;

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil

{

  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

preview.text = "hello";

}

return self;

}
```

Preview it's a simple UILabel;

Comment: show us you header file and synthesize

Answer (score 1):

because your iboutlets (the UI components) are loaded in the viewdidload method 
you can't acces them in the init

Comment: Do you mean 'you can't acces them in the init' ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just because you created your view controller from a nib doesn't mean it immediately loads it.

You need to put any code that requires ui components to be created in `viewDidLoad` i.e.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    preview.text = "hello";
}
```

If you check, `preview` will be `nil` inside your init method so setting text on it won't work!

Comment: Ok.A have a next task.I create a NSDictionary with some data from plist and i need create a buttons equals count of variables in plist.I cannot call a method from viewdidload.And i can load data to NSDictionary outside viewdidload?

Comment: ".I cannot call a method from viewdidload" yes you can, why not